# lost space in Ubuntu 12.04 along with windows 7

Tags: storage

I have successfully installed Ubuntu 12.04 along with Windows 7 (dual boot). My original hard drive was of 2T and after Ubuntu installation it became 1T for windows and remaining 1T space is missing both in windows and in Ubuntu. I need your help in recovering the remaining 1T and associate it with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not able to see the 1TB using(logging in into) windows(or a software in windows) then its okay because windows cannot detect the EXT4 filesystem used by linux.

Also to check if that 1tb has been given to Ubuntu, you can either install Gparted orJust go to the DISK UTILITY to check where the space has been occupied.

P.S: If dusing installation you had selected the option "INSTALL ALONGSIDE WINDOWS7"
     then by default Ubuntu has reassigned the 1TB to itself and re sized the 2tb of only windows partition(mostly NTFS) to 1TB.(You can obviously confirm like stated b4 using Gparted or DISK UTILITY)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. yes, I have intalled "INSTALLED ALONGSIDE WINDOWS7" and indeed it has reassign the space. I will install Gparted. I want to know here the Ubuntu portion of the disc can be found? I mean the location?

Comment: You are welsome Lucy :)

And yeah.The partition can be seen from DISK UTILITY and GPARTED

:)

Answer (score 0):

Use gparted to see the partition on your hard disk. I cannot understand: you have 2 partitions (1 windows and 1 ubuntu) of 500 gb each? 
Otherwise You can use gparted to move or resize the partition. In windows 7 you can use the Device Manager to expand your hard disk also.